# Count repeating number in an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to make a program that will count how many numbers has been repeated for example

arr1[]={1,2,3,4,5,1,2} the output should be 2 because number 1 and 2 has a duplicate

arr2[]={1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3} the output should be 3 because number 1,2 and 3 has a duplicate

i cannot see a specific answer to my question since the answer always comes up is with count how many times does the number repeated in an array

anyway heres my own code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int arr[64],n,clamp=0,ctr=0,maxv = 0;
    cout<<"Enter desired number of element"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"Enter "<<n<<" numbers"<<endl;
    for(int x=0;x<n;x++)
    {
         cin>>arr[x];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]>maxv)
        maxv=arr[i];
    }
    for(int y=0;y<=maxv;y++)
    {
        for(int x=0;x<n;x++)
        {
            if(y==arr[x])
            {
                ctr++;
            }
            if(ctr>=2)
            {
                clamp++;
                ctr=0;
                break;
            }
        }
        ctr=0;
    }
    cout<<"The amount of repeated elements is "<<clamp<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is sorting and then checking acceptable?

Comment: (you can also use a hashtable)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: You don't realize you have already found the step 1 of some of many possible methods?

Comment: i do have but they are way too advance from my knowledge in c++ thats why i want to keep it simple so i can keep track the logic and then advance to the next step

Comment: Is this an exercise from a book? Then read teh related chapter. Is this some homework exercise at school? Then study the lecture... At least show us what you have tried... and do not forget to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use a std::map and check whether the key is already in it.
Then you just increment the value every time you want to push something into this index.

Comment: I also would use a std::map for that. It's faster than sorting the array and less effort to program

Answer (score 0):

I would use a hashtable (std::map) wich stores if an character has already been there:

```
#include<map>

int GetRepeatingCharacterNumber(int* pArray, int nCount)
{
    std::map<int, int> exists;
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nCount; ++i)
    {
        if (exists.find(pArray[i]) == exists.end())
        {
            //not found
            //add to map
            exists[pArray[i]] = 1;          
        }
        else
        {
            //already in there
            //check if it already counted
            if (exists[pArray[i]] == 1)
            {
                //second time found
                result++;
            }
            exists[pArray[i]] += 1;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out elsewhere, `std::map` is the most obvious solution, but it can be done more concisely than in sebi's answer

```
template<typename Iterator,
         typename Compare = std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type> >
size_t max_number_of_repetitions(Iterator begin, const Iterator end)
{
  using key = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;
  std::map<key, size_t, Compare> rep;
  size_t max_rep = 0;
  for(; begin!=end; ++begin)
    max_rep = std::max(max_rep, ++(rep[*begin]));
  return max_rep;
}

int main()
{
  int arr1 [] = {1,2,3,4,5,1,2};
  int arr2 [] = {1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3};
  std::cout<<max_number_of_repetitions(std::begin(arr1),std::end(arr1))<<'\n'
           <<max_number_of_repetitions(std::begin(arr2),std::end(arr2))<<'\n';
}
```

prints

```
2
3
```